# Foreach loop with string array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want the code to be same as:

```
addr = `TX_B+'h00;
addr = `TX_B+'h04;
addr = `TX_B+'h08;
addr = `TX_B+'h0C;
addr = `TX_B+'h10;
```

by using `foreach` (or others that achieve same effect)
but it can't work.  Is there any syntax error?

```
reg [5] TX_ADDR = {"00", "04", "08", "0C", "10"};
int i;

foreach (TX_ADDR[i])
begin
  addr = `TX_B + TX_ADDR[i];
end
```

Comment: `reg [5] TX_ADDR` is illegal. Maybe you meant `string TX_ADDR[5]`. See https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `TX_ADDR`  should have been a syntax error.  The Cadence simulator gave me an error, but the Synopsys simulator did not.  Try your code on different simulators on EDAPlayground.

Here is some code which  compiles cleanly and runs on both simulators:

```
`define TX_B 1

module tb;

reg [7:0] TX_ADDR [5] = {'h00, 'h04, 'h08, 'h0C, 'h10};
int i;
int addr;

initial begin
    foreach (TX_ADDR[i])
    begin
      addr = `TX_B + TX_ADDR[i];
      $display("addr=%0d", addr);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
addr=1
addr=5
addr=9
addr=13
addr=17
```

Since you did not post a complete code example, I made several assumptions.  I doubt you really wanted string values for your array there, but if you really do, you need to convert them to numeric values to for the addition.